# How can I prevent RequestCache from being overriden

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am implementing multi-factor authentication using Spring Authorization Server (OAuth 2.0). Essentially, I have three endpoints:

```
/login
/verify-otp
/oauth2/authorize?{oauth_params} (default Spring Authorization Server endpoint)
```

When a user attempts to log in, they are redirected to **/oauth2/authorize** with the required parameters. Spring Authorization Server checks whether the user has been authenticated. If not, the user is redirected to another endpoint, **/login**. At this point, the RequestCache caches the requested parameters from the oauth2 endpoint.

Everything works fine unless a user who has been redirected to the login page tries to access the **/verify-otp** endpoint without being authenticated. In this case, the RequestCache will cache the requested params from **/verify-otp** and redirect a user to **/login** endpoint again, which means that the oauth2 cached params will be overridden. As a result, when the user tries to log in with OTP again, they will not be redirected to the OAuth redirect URI.

Is there a way to prevent RequestCache from being overriden or any better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have an [mfa-sample](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/mfa-sample) branch with an [mfa-authorizationserver](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/mfa-sample/samples/mfa-authorizationserver) sample that demonstrates a working MFA setup.

**Note:** It is an older branch and is not up to date with 1.0 (`main`).

It is based on Spring Security [mfa sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/mfa).

Currently, Spring Security does not have official MFA support, so it is a bit tricky to get right.

The key elements are setting up a [custom `TrustResolver`](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/mfa-sample/samples/mfa-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/MultiFactorTrustResolver.java) and [authorization rules](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/b0bd337a39296ffa177d03c17adcfda9515aefa7/samples/mfa-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/SecurityConfiguration.java#L83-L84) that allow access based on the state the user is in while they are going through the login flow.

The state the user is in during the login flow can be changed by setting up a new `SecurityContext` in the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and each custom `@Controller` endpoint during each step of the flow.

Take a look at the sample. One thing to **watch out for** is my branch is based on Spring Security 5.7, which automatically persists a `SecurityContext` when it is set on the `SecurityContextHolder`. If you start with Spring Boot 3, you'll be using Spring Security 6, which requires the `SecurityContext` to be saved explicitly (e.g. `securityContextRepository.save(securityContext);`).

---

(I'd like to add more links to important files in my sample branch and the official Spring Security sample, but as I type this GitHub is down on a Friday night... so I'm gonna go do something fun instead of repeatedly refresh waiting for the 500s to stop. Cheers!)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did clone the project on your branch and try it out but unfortunately I got the exact same behavior in my application. Once I hit the /security-question endpoint without being authenticated and try to login with valid username / password again the application is unable to redirect me to oauth2 endpoint but instead the application redirects me to the dashboard. Is this the normal behavior that a user should not access /security-question endpoint without being authenticated.

Comment: I finally got it. I have to disable request cache from defaultSecurityFilterChain and everything now work as I expected.

Comment: Glad it is working for you. I’m not really following what you mean by accessing the security questions page without being authenticated. The flow is /authorize -> /login -> /security-question (or some factor page) -> /authorize (from request cache) right? Or do you have a different flow?

Comment: It's similar flow that you did but in my case a user may accidentally hit the /security-question before logged, for example a user changes the url in the browser manually from /login to /security question (you may wonder why would he do that me too haha). Hence he got redirected back to login page again which results in the request cache from /authorize got overriden thus even though given username, password and security question are correct he won't be able to finish the oauth2 flow.

Comment: so the flow would be /authorize -> /login => /security-question (accidentally click) -> /login -> security-question -> dashboard (instead of redirect to oauth2 consent page)

Comment: I see. I don’t find that to be a problem worth solving in most cases, but there are times when the redirect and login flow will be interrupted and require many steps. I think (need to double check) that it would also be possible to have separate RequestCache impls to deal with that, each configured or even implemented differently. One could simply ignore certain urls for example.